# Problem opening a txt file from an external url

Tags: python, file

I have problems to open a txt file from an external URL. 
The code below works fine when reading a downloaded txt file from my PC like

```
URL='grst0120.txt'
```

But it doesn't works if I try to read the same txt file from an external site like

```
URL='https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/xg94hp534/0c4841048/8w32rn389/grst0120.txt'
```

The code below opens a txt file from the USDA website an prints all the lines with the word `"December"`. The code works fine when opening a downloaded txt file from my PC but I need another method to open the same file from the internet. I appreciate any help.
Code...

```
import re

URL = "https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/xg94hp534/0c4841048/8w32rn389/grst0120.txt"

# The code fails with this external URL but it works fine if I download the txt file and 
# I change the URL pointing to my PC location, like, URL = "grst0120.txt". 

Stocks = []
LineNum = 0
pattern = re.compile("December", re.IGNORECASE)

with open (URL, 'rt') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        LineNum += 1
        if pattern.search(line) != None:
            Stocks.append((LineNum, line.rstrip('\n')))
for Stocks_found in Stocks:
    print("Line " + str(Stocks_found[0]) + ": " + Stocks_found[1])
```

Comment: `open()` does not accept external URLs.

Comment: heard of urllib ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I could see is using the urllib module to download the Textfile to a folder, then opening it from there.

```
https://stackabuse.com/download-files-with-python/
```

The use of urllib is explained quite well on that site.
Though I'm sure, there's a more efficient way to execute your task, this might be one way.

Comment: Thank you. I think that this is the best option. Downloaded first and read it then.

Answer (score 3):

`open()` does not accept URLs but only paths to local files instead. For Python 3.x you can use [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) instead:

```
import urllib.request

URL = "https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/xg94hp534/0c4841048/8w32rn389/grst0120.txt"

data = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)

for line in data:
    print(line)
```